# soundcloud widget: autoplay not consistantly working in firefox 16

Tags: firefox, iframe, widget, soundcloud, autoplay

When trying to load a soundcloud widget in an iframe, in Firefox 16 it's not always autoplaying.

I've configured the link as follows:

```
iframeElement.setAttribute('src','http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F19746506&auto_play=true&show_artwork=false');
```

In Chrome & IE9 the track is always triggered as expected. However, in Firefox 16 slightly over half the time it's not playing automatically.

I'm clueless how to trigger it. What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the underlying Flash component which causes the autoplay feature to behave strangely. It's only happening on Firefox, because it doesn't support MP3 playback with HTML5 audio, so we have to use Flash there. There should be a fix going out next week. You can also use the [Widget API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) to control playback programmatically.

Comment: thank you! I was experimenting with that API but I couldn't get it work. But with "var widget1 = SC.Widget(iframeElement);" it's solved. thanks a ton!